# Override click on table with link in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

I have a link on top of a table which collapses and opens up an inner table when the table  gets clicked on anywhere on its area. I am trying to have the div disappears and creating new divs when i click on the link. It seems that clicking on the link is overriden and collapses the table as opposed to making that same div disappear and creating new divs. Is there a property which enforces that clicking on the link will not be overriden?thanks

```
<a href=""  ng-click="changeDivs()"    >disappear</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

may be you can try ng-show as false in your function when  you click on it

Answer (score 0):

You are using  tag which the href overrides ng-click in Angular.js. So as long as you don't need to send user to an URL, then you shouldn't use  tag. basicly you should  use a button tag if you don't need a uri.

but if you insist to use  tag for any reasons, u can use ti like this :

```
<a href ng-click="changeDivs()">disappear</a>
```

Comment: thank you but these brackets do not work, they actually appear on the rendered page. I am not certain what you mean by me using tags, if i dont use tags then the content appear as text as opposed to being angular code.

Comment: no need for brackets, I edit it, I mean you are using wrong tag, that mean instead of <a> tag you can use <button> tag , since you don't have any URL to put in href="'